# Pygame and 3D stuff without external libraries

Tags: python, 3d, pygame

I know this is gonna be a doozy of a question to answer, but I'm wondering how I would make a simple 3D environment out of pygame to place an image at different points on the X, Y, and Z axes. (Yes, axis plural is axes.) I'd really rather have this all done by hand, with no pre-made modules or libraries. What I'm looking for as an answer is something like a link to a page about how to do 3D stuff, or just about it. So what sort of formulas would be required, the formulas themselves, information, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pygame, by default, is a 2D game engine so there is no built-in support for 3D but you can implement your own 3D operations with extensive math. Take a look [here](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/pygame-3d-graphics-tutorial).